# Get a user's "interesting tags"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

The current implementation of the API does not provide a way for us to fetch a user's "interesting tags". The `/users/{id}/tags` unfortunately returns all tags a user has participated in, which I'm not sure how it is helpful. It would be nice if I could highlight "interesting" questions in my app just like the trilogy sites do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely private and should not be exposed by a read-only API that does not authenticate for that user.

Comment: I was initially thinking "What's the big deal, so what if everyone sees that I am interested in C#?" with respect to the current trilogy. With the SE coming together and the inevitability of some sites that may have more "colorful" topics, I came around to your thinking. (Replace C# with naked-cake-dancing).

Comment: @TheHurt: You know that comment is public, right? :)

Answer (score 4):

This is private per-user information.  Accordingly we can't expose it until some sort of user auth is in place, which isn't a v1 target.

Comment: Whew! That's what I was hoping.

Comment: Now that auth is in place, will this be reconsidered?