# Get favorited tags of user

Tags: feature-request, api-v2

This was requested in [1](https://stackapps.com/questions/399/get-a-users-interesting-tags) and declined because of a missing authentication method.

Now that authentication is in place, is there a way to retrieve the favorited tags of a user (myself)?

Comment: I'd like to use this feature too

Comment: Yep. I would be nice feature to have

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
The feature appears to be present in the, so far, undocumented API version 2.3.  See [captncraig's answer on this page](https://stackapps.com/a/7358).

---

<s>After all these years, it looks like this might never get implemented.</s>  However, it's not too hard to get the information via page scraping.

1. From a browser or scraper that is **logged in** as the user, fetch the site's question page. (EG: `http://stackapps.com/questions`)
2. Parse the `#interestingTags > a.post-tag` nodes.

For example, **this javascript will work in the browser console** while logged in to and browsing any Stack Exchange page:

```
var favTagNodes = $('<div><a class="post-tag">** Error loading favorite tags. **</a></div>') 
.load ("/questions #interestingTags>a.post-tag", function (response, status, xhr) {
    var favoriteTags    = favTagNodes.find ("a.post-tag").map ( function () {
        return this.textContent;
    } )
    .get ();

    console.log ("favoriteTags: ", favoriteTags);
} );
```

---

1. It can be made into a bookmarklet, or userscript, or browser extension.
2. It even works cross-domain when using `GM_xmlhttpRequest` and a full URL.
3. Be sure to cache the results for at least an hour to avoid excessive scrapes of the page and possible banning. See also: [*Etiquette of Screen-scraping Stack Overflow?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Good news! The (yet undocumented) api version 2.3 has this feature.

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/{id}/tag-preferences?access_token=...&key=...&site=StackOverflow.com` will give you something like:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tag_preference_type": "favorite_tag",
      "user_id": 9999999,
      "tag_name": "git"
    }, {
      "tag_preference_type": "favorite_tag",
      "user_id": 9999999,
      "tag_name": "go"
    }, {
      "tag_preference_type": "ignored_tag",
      "user_id": 9999999,
      "tag_name": "java"
    }
    ... 
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9997
}
```

Comment: Confirmed.  Note that `api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/me/tag-preferences` does not yet work.