# How can I get a list of favorite/ignored tags?

Tags: support, api-v2, ignored-tags

I can not find an API method method that would provide me with a set of favorite/ignored tags for a given user. Is there such a method? If not, is there a recommended way to get this information?

Comment: Related: [Feature Request: Get favorited tags of user](http://stackapps.com/q/3754/7653).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) does not provide a method to get the user's question-page, display preferences -- including Favorite or Ignored tags.

Currently, the only way for your app to get these is to *browse* to [the questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and scrape the tags from the right-hand column.

If your app is running in the user's browser and the user is logged-in, this is a piece of cake.

Otherwise, your app must somehow obtain the user's login credentials, which most users would be justifiably unwilling to provide.